# If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open sets in some metric space $X$, prove that they are seperated.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

> If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open sets in some metric space $X$, prove that they are separated.

---

**My (Attempted) Proof**:

$A$ and $B$ disjoint $\implies$ $A \cap B = \emptyset$

Since $A$ is open, every point $p \in A$ is an interior point of $A$. Thus for every $p$ in $A$, we can find a neighborhood $N(p)$, such that $N(p) \subset A$

Let $A'$ be the set of all limit points of $A$. We want to show $a' \in A' \implies a' \not\in B$

If $a' \in A'$ and $a' \in A$, then $a' \not\in B$ (as $A$ and $B$ are disjoint). Now if $a' \in A'$ and $a' \not\in A'$, then $a'$ must be a boundary point of $A'$

Assume $a' \in B$. Since $B$ is open, $a'$ must be an interoir point of $B$. Therefore there exists a neighborhood, $N(a') \subset B$, with radius $\delta$, i.e. $d(a', q)) < \delta$. But since $a'$ is a boundary point of $A$, that would imply there are some $q \in N(a')$, that are also in $A$. But those $q$ must also be in $B$, implying $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Thus $a' \not \in B$.

Therefore no $a' \in A'$ is an element of $B$ and $A' \cap B = \emptyset$. Let $\overline{A}$, denote the closure of $A$. It is clear that $(\overline{A} = A \cup A') \cap B = \emptyset$.

We repeat this proof for $B$ to show $(\overline{B} = B \cup B') \cap A = \emptyset$, and thus we have $A$ and $B$ as separated sets as desired. $\ \square$

---

Is my proof correct, and logically sound and rigorous? Also if you have any feedback on my proof writing skills, and suggestions as to where I can improve I would love to hear them!

Comment: "Thus for every $p$ in $A$, we can find a neighborhood $N(p)$, such that $N(p) \subset A$" Do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subset$? Because if you mean a strict subset, then the statement is false...

Comment: @5xum, Are you sure? I've never used the term *strict subset* before. But I am using $\subset$ here in the definition that $N(p) \subset A \iff (\lambda \in N(p) \implies \lambda \in A)$. Is this statement correct in this definition of $\subset$?

Comment: Nah, you're good then. There is some confusion about the sign $\subset$, as some understand the sign as implying that one set is a *strict* subset of the other in the sense that if $A\subset B$, then $A\neq B$. But obviously, you don't use that definition, so no problem. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but possibly unnecessarily convoluted - for example, you clearly can simply let $A$ itself be your neighbourhood $N(p)$ for $p\in A$.

You want to show $\overline A\cap B=\emptyset$. But simply as $A$ is open, we know the complement $B^c$ is closed and from $A\cap B=\emptyset$, we have $A\subseteq B^c$. Consequently, $\overline A\subseteq B^c$ and as $B^c\cap B=\emptyset$, also $\overline A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Since your proof does not take metrics into account, it is also much more general -  it proves that any two open sets in a topological space are separated.